# javascript canvas popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a doubt. how to move the pop up above find atm locations. I tried it by changing html structure but its not working.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/s6hBG/18/)

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what does the javascript has to do with your popup? The javascript isn't tied to the HTML, either.

Comment: Hi Dirk,thanks for your reply. i am providing the link which i tried out http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/s6hBG/19/. I tied javascript since it involves canvas.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Is it a menu with a draggable link to 'find ATM locations'? Ie that why you need the javascript, to make it draggable?

Comment: when i click this link <a class="openme">Find ATM Locations</a>
the pop up should come above it should not come down....

Comment: I'm on an iPad right now, all I see is the findATM box. Does it have to be draggable? Otherwise you could use only CSS.

Comment: It does not need to be draggable when u click the atm link i want the popup to displayed above it....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Javascript, CSS will do just fine. You need to create a separate div that you can display and hide with the clickon the 'search ATM' link. Here's a detailed howto on displaying and hiding a div with CSS:

http://www.devinrolsen.com/css-hide-and-display-content/

Comment: can you please tell me with respect to my code since its hard to understand i am providing my fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/s6hBG/21/